# Uploadify stops working in IE after a couple of uploads

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, uploadify

I have an uploadify instance that sends a file to the server in an AJAXy way. It's working fine in Chrome, but in IE it will randomly stop working after the first or second or third upload. When it does stop working the onSelect function does fire, but nothing else happens.

How would you go about debugging this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: might be IE caching your AJAX calls, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. you can beat it by adding a cache: false, to the AJAX options

Answer (score 0):

A first step would be to use the **Internet Explorer** console to see if an error is shown (*F12 on IE9*).

After checking that, you might want to place a console logger (*very easy, lots of tutorial for that*), to have some feedbacks when something goes wrong.

You can use the callbacks of **Uploadify** to have more precise informations.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hello, sorry I should have mentioned that there is no error in the IE console.  I am using the console to verify that onSelect is working.  onSelect fires and then nothing...

Comment: Maybe you could add `function(result) { debug('onSelect : ' + result); }` to the **onSelect** callback to see if the event returns something, maybe an error.